# IndexTank autocomplete: modifying the autocomplete field text for each result returned

Tags: ruby, heroku, indextank

I have a Ruby/Sinatra application deployed on Heroku and I am using the IndexTank plugin to provide Full Text Search capability.

I am currently using the out of the box autocomplete functionality as per the [IndexTank Autocomplete Documentation](http://indextank.com/documentation/tutorial-autocomplete)

Currently I have indexed my documents such that the default :text field contains the city name and country name of a document.  ie:

```
@index.document("1").add({:text => "London England"})
```

When I do a search in the default autocomplete field it does in fact work and return a result, however not what I would have expected, or liked.

When I type in '**lon**' into the field, it returns '**london**'.  This is indeed the correct document but I was hoping that it would actually return me '**London England**'.

Does anybody know how I go about modifying the data that is rendered in the autocomplete field dropdown so that it displays '**London England**' when I search for '**lon**'?

---

**UPDATE**

I have also tried the [InstantLinks](https://github.com/flaptor/indextank-jquery/wiki/Instantlinks) functionality as suggested in the comments but this also does not **quite** do what I need to do.  It seems that both solutions do about 80% of what I need, but unfortunately I need something extra.

The two things about InstantLinks that don't work as I need is:

- While I can select which field from the index to display in the drop down (which is what I couldn't do with the Autocomplete functionality), when I use the arrow keys to select the options in the drop down, the selected option does not display in the text field.
- When I do select an entry from the drop down, I am taken to another page, the URL of which is supposed to have been pulled from the index.  All I want to happen is the value of the entry selected to be populated into the original text field.

So, unfortunately I can't see how InstantLinks is going to give me the functionality I am after either.

Comment: Are you also indexing "London" by itself?

Comment: Nope, as per my example above, I am adding "London England" to the index for the document

Comment: Cool, just making sure because if you had two "London England" probably would not show until "London E" was typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally worked out a way to solve my problem however, I was not able to use either the Autocomplete or InstantLinks functionality provided by IndexTank.

In short what I did was use the out of the box jQuery autocomplete widget (which I know the IndexTank Autocomplete uses under the covers) to call a restful service I created which queries the IndexTank index.

First I created the restful service in my Sinatra Application

```
get '/index/' do
    term = params['term']

    #Query IndexTank index using the IndexTank::Client

    #Parse index search results and return an array of the suggestions as JSON
end
```

Next, I used the jQuery autocomplete widget to use my restful service as a remote source.  First there is my HTML input:

```
<form id="search_form" action="/" method="POST">
    <input id="search_field" name="search_field" type="text">
</form>
```

Then the javascript to bind the autocomplete widget to the input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_field").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/index/",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { term: request.term },
          success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
              return {label: __highlight(item, request.term),
                value: item};
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      // only change here was to replace .text() with .html()
      return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( $( "<a></a>" ).html(item.label) )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });

  function __highlight(s, t) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("("+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t)+")", "ig" );
    return s.replace(matcher, "<strong>$1</strong>");
  }
```

And there you have it, an autocomplete field that queries an IndexTank index and displays the desired index field in the suggestions drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [InstantLinks](https://github.com/flaptor/indextank-jquery/wiki/Instantlinks) instead.

If you really want to tweak autocomplete, you should change the _renderItem property of the jQuery UI widget associated with Indextank Autocomplete.

```
$("#query").data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) { .. }
```

See [jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) for an example.

Comment: I have tried InstantLinks and I don't think that is exactly what I want either.  It seems that InstantLinks does not change the text field to the currently selected value in the drop down.  I want the Autocomplete functionality exactly, except the text value I want to be displayed in the drop down is the full value of the :text field in the index, as opposed to the single word I was typing.  Therefore, when I type in 'Lon' into the field I would like to see 'London, England' displayed in the dropdown.  Currently it just displays 'london'.  Am I able to do this with the _renderItem?

Comment: As I look closer into the Autocomplete code, I don't think chaning the _renderItem is going to help because the suggestion data has already been returned.  Under the covers the IndexTank autocomplete RESTful service is being called which is searching in the :text field which is correct.  However this service looks like it just returns the 'london' part as a suggestion instead of what I want, 'London, England'.  This doesn't seem to be something I can have any control over.  Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: In that case, you want InstantLinks, but you need to make a few changes. 

Try:
`$("#query").indextank_InstantLinks( {fields: "text,url", name:"text"});` and make sure **url** matches the field on your index for URLs .. it may be href, docid or something like that